# How to show animation when open new Window in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiscenedelegate

I have [Bottom sheet](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2019/12/11/building-bottom-sheet-in-swiftui/) I want to show it above TabBar so user tab on button inside List and it show options as Bottom sheet view

1st. I used SwiftUIX with OverlayWindow
like this

```
.windowOverlay(isKeyAndVisible: self.$optionsShown, {
            GeometryReader { _ in
                
                BottomSheetView(
                    isOpen: $optionsShown
                ) {
                    if optionsShown {
                        OptionsView()
                    }
                    
                }
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            }

        })
```

it working but without animation !

2nd. Then I read this [Post](https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/swiftui-windows/)
I tried it, it working fine with animation if I create Window inside SceneDelegate
but If I create Window outside SceneDelegate it will work without animation like SwiftUIX

Inside SceneDelegate :
[Demo Project](https://a.cl.ly/6quEYPYY)

Outside SceneDelegate :
[Demo Project](https://a.cl.ly/GGuEpr4n)

I need to create new window inside my view because I will need to pass some values, and I used bottom sheet on multiple view with different views

but I cannot figure out why the animation won't work outside SceneDelegate